# What are the best tools question - Should it stick around?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, questions, allowed-topics

[What are the best software tools for personal finance?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2301/what-are-the-best-software-tools-for-personal-finance)

Does this question still belong on our site?  I have a feeling that if it was asked today, it would be closed as not answerable/not specific, etc.

Should we delete the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest that the question be closed as `Not Constructive` a placed under historical lock.  It wouldn't be considered a good question now (wow, what a list), but certainly has historical value (lots of votes,  lots of answers, fair number of views).

Comment: I agree with this!

Comment: Je suis d'accord aussi.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea Shall you or I?

Comment: @CRoss No reason why you couldn't have, but since I'm on now, I just put it under "historical lock", though now I don't have the option to close.  Should I have done the close first, then lock?  Or it doesn't matter?  I don't think we've used the historical lock feature here, yet.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea Historical lock is fine by itself, but closing it as NC marks it for future users as "we don't do it that way anymore"