# Questions specific to a particular personal finance software product?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

Is this forum the right place to ask questions that are specific to a particular personal finance software product?

The product I have in mind is http://moneydance.com/, but it could apply equally to any such product and especially non-commercial products.

Moneydance has their own user forum but it lacks the features that make stackexchange sites so effective.

Comment: Citing some candidate example questions might help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends what your question is.  Here are the related meta-questions I could think of.

- [Should questions on the technical usage of a financial management tool be on-topic, or off-topic?](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127/should-questions-on-the-technical-usage-of-a-financial-management-tool-be-on-top)
- [Do technical questions about tools belong?](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9/do-technical-questions-about-tools-belong)
- [What are the best tools question - Should it stick around?](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-are-the-best-tools-question-should-it-stick-around)
- [Are questions about trading software are on topic](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/730/are-questions-about-trading-software-are-on-topic)

I think the consensus is that if it is on topic if you aren't shopping, asking for a recommendation, or getting technical support, it would be okay.

Comment: Although it may not be applicable to kevin, but if some users are asking questions with the intent to promote a particular site, it would be offtopic.